# python3::ssl:: _local_ certificate validation

Tags: ssl, python-3.6, pyopenssl

I am trying to do (python 3.6) the equivalent of

```
openssl verify -CApath my_dir_of_CA_certs my_cert_from_one_of_those_CAs
```

I keep looking over ssl and pyOpenSSL but nothing seems apparent.. any form of verification
for these modules require a connection which is not what the above command do. Do i miss something obvious here or it's just not possible? (and i will have to run it as system command)

Comment: Start your search at `get_verified_chain()` in `X509StoreContext`. Or `verify_certificate`.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek actually your answer is on point  (X509Store + X509StoreContext + verify_certificate) and i succeeded to reach my goal. maybe you could just give a proper answer below and i can credit you with it

Answer (score 1):

so, @patrick-mevzek was right, to do certificate verification against a (collection of) CA, with python3, one can use pyOpenSSL and do:
`x509store = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store()`
`x509store.load_locations(None, capath = ca_verify_location)`
OR
`x509store.load_locations(cafile = ca_verify_location)`  if the CAs are store in a file
`store_ctx = OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContext(x509store, x509)`
where x509 is the x509 cert object, and then
`store_ctx.verify_certificate()`